# Width of minipage inside center environment

Tags: margins, minipage, lengths

So I have three columns of content next to each other, using the minipage syntax, with the width specified in `\textwidth`, all of this placed in a center environment. Weirdly enough, if I make widths of the columns add up to the full size of `\textwidth`, it does not fit on the page. After some testing, the inner width of center appears to be only around 98.57% of `\textwidth`. E.g. the following does not fit, and the C block is put on the next line:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.10\textwidth}
    A
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.10\textwidth}
    B
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{0.7858\textwidth}
    C
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

So how does one specify the width of the page within a center environment, or how does one center some blocks that together have between 98.56% and 100% of the width of the page?

Also, I realise that it does not make much sense to center content that is exactly as wide as the page itself, so this is more a question out of curiosity than that I'm searching for a solution to some problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is a space after each `\end{minipage}`. Type `\end{minipage}%` instead and the last can be `0.8\textwidth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to sum of table width you need to add spaces between mini tables or remove this spaces. in the second case you will obtain:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

```
\documentclass{article}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.10\textwidth}
    A
  \end{minipage}% <--- added
  \begin{minipage}{0.10\textwidth}
    B
  \end{minipage}% <--- added
  \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
    C
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```